# $1^\infty=1$ or is indeterminate?

Tags: limits, problem-solving

$$\underbrace{1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot1\cdots1\cdot1}_{\infty}=1$$
because of $1^\infty$ is indeterminate?$$$$
And $$\lim_{x\to\infty}1^x=\lim_{x\to\infty}1=1?$$

Comment: It is best if you *never refer to* "$1^\infty$" or other non-existent objects such as $\frac{0}{0}$, $0\cdot\infty$, or $\infty-\infty$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In calculus, when we talk about indeterminate forms, it's usually something like this:

Suppose $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = \infty$. Then what is $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)^{g(x)}$? In this case, yes, the form is indeterminate.

Consider the logarithm: $\log f(x)^{g(x)} = g(x)\log f(x)$. We've said that $g(x)\to\infty$, and since $f(x)\to 1$, then we have $\log f(x)\to 0$. Therefore, the logarithm of our "$1^\infty$" form is a $\infty \cdot 0$ form, which is definitely indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what exactly is meant by $1^\infty $. The most natural way is to define it as a limit: $1^\infty =\lim_{n\to \infty}1^n $, and this limit is clearly equal to $1$. So, if you accep this *definition* of $1^\infty $, then it follows that $1^\infty =1$. Of course, you may choose to define this concept otherwise, and obtain, perhaps, different answers.

Comment: But, and this limit:$$\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^x$$

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^x= "(1+0)^\infty" =1\neq e$$ and $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{1}{x})^x=e$$

Comment: @marcelolpjunior that was not what the question stated. You asked about $1^\infty $, not about $\lim _{x\to \infty }f(x)^{g(x)}$ where $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty }g(x)=\infty $. As I said in my question, it's one to you to *define* what $1^\infty $ means. You now changed its meaning from what I described in my answer. So, you get a different result.